# Detecting a second click in a raycast?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

When the player clicks the fire button, a crosshair image will be instantiated, and when they click again I want the name of the crosshair image to change to boom. However, when the crosshair is instantiated the name is already boom. Thanks

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
{
    if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "fire")
    {
        if (crosshair == 1)
        {
            GameObject Aimz = Instantiate(aim, rb2D.transform.position, rb2D.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
            Aimz.name = "crosshair";

            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
            {
                if (hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "fire")
                {
                    Aimz.name = "boom";
                }
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `Input.GetMouseButtonUp(0)` instead? Holding button down can last for couple frames. Also there's no need to check button state when you did it already in the begining of the code because it'll be the same.

If you still have problem with that, please provide with bigger scope of the code. Probably your `Aimz` can be set as local variable and checked for null instead of doing that nasty `if (crosshair == 1)`.

Comment: Wrong. Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) only lasts for one frame only. But he is using both checks in the same frame

Answer (score 0):

You check on the second mouse button press in the SAME frame you check for the first one. Input.GetMouseButtonDown() will not change for this frame. Therefore Aimz.name is always assigned with "boom" as soon as you click the mouse button because both if(Input...) will result to true.

A correct solution would be this

```
if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0) && hitInfo.transform.gameObject.tag == "fire")
{
    if (Aimz.name == "") // "" = whatever your Aimz.name name is before you assign "crosshair" to it
    {
        Aimz.name = "crosshair";
        // Do your "crosshair" stuff here
    } 
    else 
    {
        Aimz.name = "boom";
        // Do your "boom" stuff here
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Can't you just attach a small script to Aimz where you count the number of clicks? With a method that reverts the number of clicks to zero after x seconds. So it would look sort of like this:

```
public int NumberOfClicks;
private bool Invoked;

void Start(){
    Invoked = false;
}

void Update(){
    if(NumberOfClicks == 1 && !Invoked){
        gameObject.name = "crosshair";
        Invoke("RevertToZero", 2);
        Invoked = true;
    }

    if(NumberOfClicks == 2 ){
        gameObject.name = "boom";
    }
}

void RevertToZero(){
     NumberOfClicks = 0;
     Invoked = false;
}
```